# Count number of named groups captured and number of named groups total in Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have two lists. One list, `ref`,contains items of regular expressions that allow for increasingly greater flexibility, and the other list, `input`, contains an input list to be matched against the regular expressions. 
So far, I am capable of creating the `match` dictionary below. Below this is the dictionary that I'm trying to create, `match_upd`. `match` consists of keys from the input, with corresponding matches from `ref` for values. The value items are made up of the second item of every matched tuple item in `ref`. In addition, each value within `match` contains the named capture group that achieved the match. The desired output, `match_upd`, would contain the same values, but each of these values would also consist of a count of the number of named capturing groups within the matched capturing group that succeeded in matching, in addition to a count of those that matched within the matched capturing group.
The example below is very abstract, and I apologize if that makes it confusing. Basically I'm trying to tally the number of optional capturing groups within a match, and also tally the number of these groups that participated in the match. I am using Python's new [regex](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) module.

```
input = [(' PREDIR NAME SUFTYP B1 ', 'CCCC, 11111'), (' NAME SUFTYP SUFDIR A1 ', 'CCCC, 11111')]

ref = [('(?P<iter1> PREDIR PRETYP NAME SUFTYP SUFDIR )|(?P<iter2> (?P<iter2pd>PREDIR )?(?P<iter2pt>PRETYP )?NAME(?P<iter2st> SUFTYP)?(?P<iter2sd> SUFDIR)? .*? )|(?P<iter3>.*? NAME .*? )', ['PREDIR,PRETYP,NAME,SUFTYP,SUFDIR,', 'CCCC, 11111']), ('(?P<iter1> NAME )|(?P<iter2> NAME )|(?P<iter3>.*? NAME .*? )', [',,NAME,,,', 'CCCC, 11111']), ('(?P<iter1> PREDIR NAME SUFTYP )|(?P<iter2> (?P<iter2pd>PREDIR )?NAME(?P<iter2st> SUFTYP)? .*? |(?P<iter3> .*? NAME .*?)', ['PREDIR,,NAME,SUFTYP,,', 'CCCC, 11111'])]

match {' NAME SUFTYP SUFDIR A1 , CCCC, 11111': (([',,NAME,,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter3'), (['PREDIR,,NAME,SUFTYP,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2'), (['PREDIR,PRETYP,NAME,SUFTYP,SUFDIR,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2')), ' PREDIR NAME SUFTYP B1 , CCCC, 11111': ((['PREDIR,,NAME,SUFTYP,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2'),['PREDIR,PRETYP,NAME,SUFTYP,SUFDIR,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2'), ([',,NAME,,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter3'))}

match_upd {' NAME SUFTYP SUFDIR A1 , CCCC, 11111': (([',,NAME,,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter3',0,0), (['PREDIR,,NAME,SUFTYP,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2',1,2), (['PREDIR,PRETYP,NAME,SUFTYP,SUFDIR,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2',2,4)), ' PREDIR NAME SUFTYP B1 , CCCC, 11111': ((['PREDIR,,NAME,SUFTYP,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2',2,2),['PREDIR,PRETYP,NAME,SUFTYP,SUFDIR,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter2',2,4), ([',,NAME,,,', 'CCCC, 11111'], 'iter3',0,0))}
```

I can generate `match` with the following code:

```
def match(i,o,addr,ref,group):
    m = regex.fullmatch(i[0],o[0])
    if m:
        addr.append(str(o).strip('('')').replace("'",""))
        ref.append(i[1])
        m = m.groupdict()
        for k,v in m.items():
            if v is not None:
                group.append(k)

addr = []
ref = []
group = []

for i in ref:
    for t in input:
        if t[1] == i[1][2]:
            match(i,t,addr,ref,group)

unmatched = []
for i in input:
    unmatched.append(str(i).strip('('')').replace("'",""))

match_iter123 = zip(addr,zip(ref,group))
unmatched123 = list((set(unmatched)) - (set(addr)))

matchdict123 = {}
[matchdict123.setdefault(k,[]).append(v) for k,v in match_iter123]

matchdict = defaultdict(tuple)

for i in match_iter123:
    matchdict[i[0]] += i[1:]

match = {k:v for k, v in matchdict.items()}
```

My attempt at appending the desired outputs for `match_upd` has not been fruitful:

```
def match(i,o,addr,ref,group,matchattributes,totalattributes):
    m = regex.fullmatch(i[0],o[0])
    if m:
        addr.append(str(o).strip('('')').replace("'",""))
        ref.append(i[1])
        m = m.groupdict()
        for k,v in m.items():
            if v is not None and re.search(r'pd|pt|sd|st',k) is None:
                group.append(k)
        for k,v in m.items():
            if v is not None and re.search(r'pd|pt|sd|st',k) is not None:
                matchattributes.append(len(k))
        for k,v in m.items():
            if re.search(r'pd|pt|sd|st',k) is not None:
                totalattributes.append(len(k))
```

I'm new to programming, so forgive me if this answer is simple. I basically need a count for the last two `for` statements. Thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: You could simplify your example considerably. Use a short regex and a short input string as the example data.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In retrospect it was a pretty easy solution. I simply needed to determine the total count for the `matchattributes` and `totalattributes` variables. The `+=` function was the solution, with the total being appended to an empty list.

```
def match(i,o,addr,ref,group,matchattributes,totalattributes):
    matchcounter = 0
    totalcounter = 0
    m = regex.fullmatch(i[0],o[0])
    if m:
        addr.append(str(o).strip('('')').replace("'",""))
        ref.append(i[1])
    m = m.groupdict()
    for k,v in m.items():
            if v is not None and re.search(r'pd|pt|sd|st',k) is None:
                group.append(k)
    for k,v in m.items():
        if v is not None and re.search(r'3(pd|pt|sd|st)',k):
            matchcounter += 1
    matchattributes.append(matchcounter)
    for k,v in m.items():
        if re.search(r'3(pd|pt|sd|st)',k):
            totalcounter += 1
    totalattributes.append(totalcounter)
```